Ubuntu 24.04 boot nstallation hangs on systemd
I am attempting to install Ubuntu 24.04 onto a new desktop PC. The installation is very strange.
What appears to be happening is that the systemd is hanging the system after starting one of its services. Basically, I am seeing it stop after the following line:
     starting systemd_rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill switch status
[OK] started systemd_rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill switch status

and then the system freezes. The installation system doesn't come up, and in fact the only thing I can do is shut off or restart the computer.
Has anyone else seen this problem? If so, do you have a way to fix it???
Editing to answer oldfred's questions:
The CPU is one of the latest Ryzen 7.
The CPU Board has 64G memory.
The main disk is a 4Tb SSD
The screen is powered by a Nvidia board
One thing of interest:  After posting this problem, I successfully installed Ubuntu V22.04 server onto the system. I then upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04. Unfortunately, after the upgrade the system rebooted -- then it froze after the same systemd line.

How new of a system? What brand/model? What video card/chip. Often last entry is not the issue, but several lines above it is the issue. Is this error from installer or from install? If really new system, you may need to try 24.10 to have newest kernel & drivers.

I have just attempted to install Ubuntu V24.10 onto this system. oldfred: the installation boot is freezing at the same place. Whatever is causing this problem was not changed with the .10 release.

May be video issue? There used to be a "safe" boot option, not sure if still there with newest. I do not have nVidia and not current on latest boot of live installer with nVidia.

There probably is a safe boot option, but it isn't in the installation  program. Maybe there should be? There is no reason for a video driver to do anything fancy when installing, anyway!  Still, as my answer below shows, you were correct: it was definitely a video issue -- though it is weird that one Nvidia card causes a hang while another does not.

I believe I found the problem.
It was the Nvidia graphics card. I was using a Nvidia GTX 1060 with 16 Gb card in my computer. I swapped it with a Nvidia GTX 1070 with 12 Gb card that I had been using with another machine.
Now my machine does not hang on anything. I am currently installing Ubuntu V24.04 without problems.
There should be some investigation as to why one Nvidia graphics card works with V24.04 while another one hangs upon booting. Unfortunately, I do not have the machines nor the device driver expertise to do this.
But I do know that the GTX 1060 somehow causes hanging upon booting Ubuntu V24.04. Hopefully, someone will investigate this so that whatever bug is in the Nvidia driver can be fixed.
